# Can you observe system property changes in Android?

Tags: android, system-properties

Is there a mechanism for observing changes in system properties from your own app in Android SDK?

For example, I want to be able to detect changes in the `system.adb.tcp.port` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think exist a mechanism to do this., but you may be able to retrieve system properties by  executing **getprop** in a [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) and retrieve its output.

or try this link : [for System.getProperty()]
 http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2):

As of API 25 there's no public API for this.  You need to dig down into internal functions that only exist to exercise the system.

See `__system_property_wait_any()` in [sys/_system_properties.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/nougat-mr2.1-release/libc/include/sys/_system_properties.h).  The need to define `_REALLY_INCLUDE_SYS__SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_H_` shows that its use is even discouraged internally.

I wouldn't use this in an app.  A quick grep of AOSP indicates that it's only used in test code, so there doesn't appear to be a "friendly" API that makes use of it.

I think you're stuck with polling [`System.getProperty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

For C/C++, please call WaitForProperty defined in "android-base/properties.h" and libbase.

For Java, please call OnPropertyChangedCallback in class Observable.